# Conditional formating based on 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I have a certain set of values wherein I use conditional formatting to highlight the top and bottom values; however, when the top value is at 100%, I have to highlight the second highest value instead.

Is there any way this could be done in Excel?

Thank you for all the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***Conditional Formatting*** selct ***New Rule*** and in ***Select a Rule Type*** select ***Use a formula to determine which cells to format*** then enter the following formula

```
=IF(LARGE($A$1:$A$10,1)=100,RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$10)=2,RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$10)=1)
```

**EDIT:**

Use this formula

```
=IF(LARGE($C$51:$C$57,1)=100,RANK(C51,$C$51:$C$57)=2,RANK(C51,$C$51:$C$57)=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think this is the formula I need; however, I'm a bit confused on how to apply this formula when the range is not within cells A1 to A10. I'm confused on what to apply in the first argument of the RANK function when the range is from, for example, B3 to B9.

Comment: @NamaChoco - Use this formula `=IF(LARGE($B$3:$B$9,1)=100,RANK(B3,$B$3:$B$9)=2,RANK(B3,$B$3:$B$9)=1)`

Comment: @NamaChoco - First arguement in `RANK` will be the first cell in range.

Comment: I see I see. I'm still having problems however when I do it on other cells. For example, I have this range of cell (C51:C57) and I apply the said formula: `=IF(LARGE($C$51:$C$57,1)=100,RANK(C51,$C$51:$C$57)=2,RANK(C51,$C$51​:$C$57)=1)`. I suddenly get this error saying that there is a problem with the said formula.

Comment: @NamaChoco - Try this `=IF(LARGE($C$51:$C$57,1)=100,RANK(C51,$C$51:$C$57)=2,RANK(C51,$C$51:$C$57)=1)`

Comment: @NamaChoco - I've added formula in answer, see edit. Copy it from answer. For some strange reasons formula in comments is adding spaces in between that's why you are getting error.